# ThePHPLeague OAuth2 Client `getAccessToken()` throws "An OAuth server error was encountered that did not contain a JSON body" error

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, slim, thephpleague, slim-4

I have been attempting to develop an API and client which communicate to each other via an implementation of ThePHPLeague's OAuth2 [server](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server) and [client](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client). Using the `curl` command in a CLI, I am able to generate a token and use it to gain access to protected resources.

User authentication relies on a [bespoke PHP solution](https://github.com/JoshuaFlood/slim-authentication-php-template) with Slim framework, which accepts a username and encrypted password stored in a database table. The same table is used for the OAuth2 implementation's user management.

When a user login attempt is successfully validated, the [AbstractProvider](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client/blob/master/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php) 's `getAccessToken()` method is called and an access token is requested from the API. Here is where the problem lies.

I have tested functionality using the `GenericProvider` class. I've also extended the provider to create my own class. Using the both providers, I see the following error when I attempt to login:

```
Slim Application Error
Type: UnexpectedValueException
Code: 0
Message: An OAuth server error was encountered that did not contain a JSON body
File: /var/www/sloth2-client-php/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php
Line: 693

#0 /.../vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php(626): 
League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->parseResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#1 /.../src/SlothProvider.php(113): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->getParsedResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request))
#2 /.../src/Controller/AuthenticationController.php(69): App\SlothProvider->getAccessToken(Object(League\OAuth2\Client\Grant\ClientCredentials))
#3 /.../vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/Strategies/RequestResponse.php(42): App\Controller\AuthenticationController->authenticate(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request), Object(Slim\Psr7\Response), Array)
#4 /.../vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Routing/Route.php(372): Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse->__invoke(Array, Object(Slim\Psr7\Request), Object(Slim\Psr7\Response), Array)
#5 /.../vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(73): Slim\Routing\Route->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
#6 /.../vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(73): Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
#7 /.../vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Routing/Route.php(333): Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
#8 /.../vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Routing/RouteRunner.php(65): Slim\Routing\Route->run(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
#9 /.../vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php(58): Slim\Routing\RouteRunner->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
#10 /.../vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(132): Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->process(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request), Object(Slim\Routing\RouteRunner))
#11 /.../vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/ErrorMiddleware.php(89): class@anonymous->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
#12 /.../vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(132): Slim\Middleware\ErrorMiddleware->process(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request), Object(class@anonymous))
#13 /.../vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(73): class@anonymous->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
#14 /.../vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(206): Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
#15 /.../vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(190): Slim\App->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request))
#16 /.../public/index.php(8): Slim\App->run()
#17 {main}
```

The `SlothProvider` class mentioned in the stack trace is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Tool\BearerAuthorizationTrait;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use UnexpectedValueException;

class SlothProvider extends AbstractProvider
{
  use BearerAuthorizationTrait;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->clientId = getenv('OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID');
    $this->clientSecret = getenv('OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET');
    $this->redirectUri = getenv('OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI');
  }

  /**
   * Get authorization url to begin OAuth flow
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function getBaseAuthorizationUrl()
  {
    return getenv('OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_URL');
  }

  /**
   * Get access token url to retrieve token
   *
   * @param  array $params
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function getBaseAccessTokenUrl(array $params)
  {
    return getenv('OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL');
  }

  /**
   * Get provider url to fetch user details
   *
   * @param  AccessToken $token
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function getResourceOwnerDetailsUrl(AccessToken $token)
  {
    // You don't have one. You might consider throwing an exception here so
    // that, when this is called, you get an error and can code your
    // application to ensure that nothing calls this.
    //
    // Note that $this->getResourceOwner() is the most likely culprit for
    // calling this. Just don't call getResourceOwner() in your code.
  }

  /**
   * Get the default scopes used by this provider.
   *
   * This should not be a complete list of all scopes, but the minimum
   * required for the provider user interface!
   *
   * @return array
   */
  protected function getDefaultScopes()
  {
    return ['basic'];
  }

  /**
   * Check a provider response for errors.
   *
   * @throws IdentityProviderException
   * @param  ResponseInterface $response
   * @param  array $data Parsed response data
   * @return void
   */
  protected function checkResponse(ResponseInterface $response, $data)
  {
    // Write code here that checks the response for errors and throws
    // an exception if you find any.
  }

  /**
   * Generate a user object from a successful user details request.
   *
   * @param array $response
   * @param AccessToken $token
   * @return \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\ResourceOwnerInterface
   */
  protected function createResourceOwner(array $response, AccessToken $token)
  {
    // Leave empty. You can't use this, since you don't have a clear
    // resource owner details URL. You might consider throwing an
    // exception from here, as well. See note on
    // getResourceOwnerDetailsUrl() above.
  }

  /**
   * Requests an access token using a specified grant and option set.
   *
   * @param  mixed $grant
   * @param  array $options
   * @throws IdentityProviderException
   * @return AccessTokenInterface
   */
  public function getAccessToken($grant, array $options = [])
  {
    $grant = $this->verifyGrant($grant);
    $params = [
      'client_id'     => $this->clientId,
      'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret,
      'redirect_uri'  => $this->redirectUri,
    ];
    $params   = $grant->prepareRequestParameters($params, $options);
    $request  = $this->getAccessTokenRequest($params);
    $response = $this->getParsedResponse($request);
    if (false === is_array($response)) {
      throw new UnexpectedValueException(
        'Invalid response received from Authorization Server. Expected JSON.'
      );
    }
    $prepared = $this->prepareAccessTokenResponse($response);
    $token    = $this->createAccessToken($prepared, $grant);
    return $token;
  }
}
```

I would like to know what this error means and how to solve it.

Comment: The `SlothProvider` here doesn't match the stack trace. At least, I expected line 113 to be `$response = $this->getParsedResponse($request);`, but that's line 121...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server is responded with a 500 status code with a body that couldn't be decoded by `json_decode()`. the actual decoding message from `json_last_error_msg()` can be found in the `UnexpectedValueException`'s previous exception's `getMessage().

To find out what it is, try catching the exception from `$response = $this->getParsedResponse($request);` and then throwing the previous exception. e.g.

```
    try {
        $response = $this->getParsedResponse($request);
    } catch (UnexpectedValueException $e) {
        if ($e->getPrevious()) {
            // json_decode() error message is in $e->getPrevious()->getMessage().
            // An easy way to see it is to throw the previous exception:
            throw $e->getPrevious();
        }
    }
```

Hopefully the error message will give you a clue as to what went wrong. Otherwise, you need to look at the Request and Response objects that were sent/received. You'll need to inspect the `getParsedResponse()` method within `League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider` to do that.

Comment: In my case, I am getting empty string for $request and the very same error message (btw I tried with Laravel 6)

Comment: btw I tried with Laravel 6 and 5.4, the Microsoft sample worked with Laravel 5.4 but NOT with Laravel 6